Use a different config::get config when using testthat
Is there a possibility to set a different Sys.getenv("R_CONFIG_ACTIVE") value when run in tests using testthat?
For example, my config.yml might look like this:
default:
  db: "my-prod.db"
test:
  db: "my-test.db"

When I run config::get("db") from a non-test environment I want to get my-prod.db but when I use testthat::test_dir() or devtools::test() or shiny::runTests() I want to get my-test.db.
I would be able to influence this by setting Sys.setenv("R_CONFIG_ACTIVE" = "test").
One possible solution is to change tests/testthat.R to use withr::with_envvar() like so
withr::with_envvar(
  c("R_CONFIG_ACTIVE" = "test"),
  test_dir(
    "./testthat",
    env = shiny::loadSupport(),
    reporter = c("progress", "fail")
  )
)

but this does not change the envvar when I run a testfile locally, eg source("tests/testthat/foo.R").
